# Password not getting masked in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i am using jenkins masking plugin to mask the passwords.

I have an user (i054564) defined in credentials as username/password type

The user name /password is defined in the bindings section as well as in the mask password subsection of Build environment section.So whenever i am using that user/password in my build job as a variable, the password is not masked and logged in the console

Some snapshots have been attached to depict the problem

Snapshot -1 Build specific settings
Snapshot -2 Credentials settings
Snapshot -3 Manage Jenkins Mask password settings

[image]

[image]
[image]

Strange thing is initially it works and then after 2-3 builds it stops working.

please let me know if you need any further details

best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: I am having same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"Inject passwords to the build as environment variables"** from Build Environment and defined its value as your "password parameter". ( password parameter - for which you can ask user to enter the password at run time). (e.g.: define inject password value as : **${password_parameter}** ).

The password which you will pass while running job will display as [*******]